# How to make a html page to show content from another url

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to make a html page that act kind like google cache.

Say in my homepage HOME, I have a link A to a website B, and when I click on A, the page that comes out will display the content of another page, with a floating bar on top that has some functions of my own choices.

For example, I want my link to show google.com, but I also want to add a button(floating bar, anything)  to that google.com that allows me to return to my own webpage when pressed.

Can someone provide me some useful resources for me too look at, or even better a solution template? :)

Thanks!

Comment: the only real way to display external page content without having explicit permissions to, say, ajax portions away from the original host is via iframes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An iframe sounds like it may be what you need, but I'm not 100% sure after reading your description. The iframe will show content from another URL in your page. Once you have that all you need to do is style the page and use CSS/JavaScript to add in your functionality as described.

Check out this:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 11):

You could use an `<iframe>` in order to display an external webpage within your webpage.
Just place the url of the webpage that you want to display inside the quotes of the `src` attribute.

```
<iframe src="http://www.webpage.com" width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the general idea:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Click Here</a>
<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.w3schools.com" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Some jQuery (not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frame').hide();

    $('#link').click(function () {
        $('#frame').show();
    })
})
```

Style it as necessary

**Note** - this answer in no way endorses w3schools.com :-) . Please see [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)/

Answer (score 3):

Either you use an iframe or you load the site via AJAX into a div (e.g. using jQuerys `load()` method).

Answer (score 0):

I found Kevin Gourney's answer to be most straight forward and helpful. I'm using this to work around Adobe Spark's Domain limitation and created a simple one liner index.html file and tweaked the code as follows:

```
<iframe src="PasteAdobeSparkPageLinkHere" width=100% height=100%></iframe>
```